# phpseclib scp->get(remote_file_path [, $localFile]) ; returns 1 extra (NULL) character

Tags: php, phpseclib

It seems that phpseclib's scp get function returns an extra NULL at the end of file that was not in the original.

I have written a script to demonstrate the problem.  This script will use phpseclib scp->put() to put a file to user@localhost as /tmp/somefile.  Then it will use scp->get() to return that file.  (scp->get() is run both with and without local filename, to demonstrate where the problem might lie.)  The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/www/cgi-bin/phpseclib') ;
require_once('Crypt/RSA.php');
require_once('Net/SSH2.php');
require_once('Net/SCP.php');

function executeSSHCommand($ssh, $command) {
    $result = $ssh->exec($command) ;
    printf("    cmd: %s (%s)\n", $command, ($result === false ? 'ERROR' : 'OK') ) ;
    if (is_string($result) && strlen($result) > 0) {
        $responseLines = explode("\n", $result) ;
        foreach ($responseLines as $line) {
            if (strlen(trim($line)) > 0)
                printf("        > %s", $line ) ;
            }
        }        
    }

function toHumanPerms($perms) {
    $rtnVal = '' ;
    $workPerms = $perms ;
    foreach ([ 'o', 'g', 'u' ] as $type) {
        $thisPerms = ($workPerms & 0x07) ;
        $workPerms >>= 3 ;
        $r = ($thisPerms & 0x04) ? 'r' : '' ;
        $w = ($thisPerms & 0x02) ? 'w' : '' ;
        $x = ($thisPerms & 0x01) ? 'x' : '' ;
        if (strlen($rtnVal) > 0) $rtnVal .= ',' ;
        $rtnVal .= $type . '=' . $r . $w . $x ;
        }
    return $rtnVal ;
    }

$home = getenv('HOME') ;
$system = 'localhost' ;
$user = getenv('LOGNAME') ;
$hostString = $user . '@' . $system ;

$key = new Crypt_RSA() ;
if ( ! $key->loadKey(file_get_contents($home . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.ssh/id_rsa'))) {
    die("Could not load private key.\n") ;
    }
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($system) ;
if ($ssh) {
    if ($ssh->login($user, $key)) {
        $scp = new Net_SCP($ssh) ;
        $localFile = (count($argv) > 1 ? $argv[1] : $home . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.bashrc' ) ;   // If not specified in $argv then copy /etc/hosts
        $remoteFile = '/tmp/' . preg_replace('%[/]%','-',$localFile) ; // For example /tmp/-etc-hosts
        $copyBack = $localFile . '-copiedBack' ;
        $fileSize = filesize($localFile) ;
        $success = $scp->put($remoteFile , $localFile, NET_SCP_LOCAL_FILE) ;
        printf("    put: %s -> %s: %s\n", $localFile, $remoteFile, ($success === true ? 'OK' : '*ERROR*') ) ;
        if ($success) {
            $permsString = toHumanPerms(fileperms($localFile)) ;
            $command = 'chmod ' . $permsString . ' ' . escapeshellarg($remoteFile) ;
            executeSSHCommand($ssh, $command) ;
            $fileModTime = date('YmdHi.s', filemtime($localFile)) ;
            $command = sprintf('touch -t %s %s', $fileModTime, escapeshellarg($remoteFile)) ;
            executeSSHCommand($ssh, $command) ; // Execute but do not write to terminal.  (Write to log, though)
            $remoteData = $scp->get($remoteFile) ;           // copy file to local variable
            $success = $scp->get($remoteFile, $copyBack) ;   // copy file to filesystem
            printf("    get: %s -> %s: %s\n\n", $remoteFile, $copyBack, $success === true ? 'OK' : '*ERROR*' ) ;
            printf("Original file size was %d, returned data size is %d, returned file size is %d\n", $fileSize, strlen($remoteData), filesize($copyBack)) ;
            }
        }
    else {
        printf("**** Unable to authenticate user %s at host %s. ****\n", $user, $system ) ;
        }
    }
else {
    printf("**** Unable to connect to server %s. ****\n", $system) ;
    }
```

If a parameter is passed, then that parameter will be used as the source filename.  Target filename will be /tmp/ plus the source filename, but slashes will be replaced by dash.  For example:

```
testscp /path/to/file
```

The target filename will be /tmp/-path-to-file

If no filename is passed, then $HOME/.bashrc (and /tmp/-home-username-.bashrc) will be used.

When I execute this with any regular file (text, binary, whatever), the file that is returned by get(..., $filename) and the string returned by get(...) are one byte longer than the original, in every case I've tried except one: Original filename was empty.  The empty-file case worked correctly, but in all other cases, it seems an extra NULL character is thrown in at the end by get().

The file written by put($filename, $targetname, , NET_SCP_LOCAL_FILE) is a correct copy of the original (proven by diff) in every case.

I have been unable to determine a cause for this.  Since it seems consistently wrong, I would assume that either the issue is widely known or I'm doing it incorretly.  Hopefully the latter.

It's tempting to follow usage of scp->get() with an operation to remove null from the end if present... but there may be cases where that null is supposed to be there (other circumstances for which an extra NULL is not sent).  So that's no good.

Does anyone reading this have an idea what I might do to resolve this, or the approach to reporting the problem if it is such?

Thanks.

UPDATE: For now, I have modified phpseclib/Net/SCP.php as follows:

In function get(), right after these two lines (lines 284 and 285 in my copy):

```
while ($size < $info['size']) {
    $data = $this->_receive();
```

I have added the following:

```
    // Following added by Lovelady, 6-May-2023 because scp->get() always returned an extra byte for non-zero get.
    $expected = $info['size'] - $size ;         // Lovelady
    if (strlen($data) == $expected + 1)         // Lovelady (If exactly 1 byte too many...)
        $data = substr($data, 0, $expected) ;   // Lovelady
    // Above added by Lovelady, 6-May-2023 because scp->get() always returned an extra byte for non-empty file.
```

At some point, unless someone else does it, I may go back and try to figure out why **$this->receive()** returns that extra NULL at the end.

I consider my current answer less than ideal, but relatively safe since the routine already knows how many bytes it should receive, and has gone over that by exactly 1.

Comment: This is an old issue: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/146 In reading that bug report I gather the biggest obstacle towards getting this fixed is reproducibility. The phpseclib author's email is terrafrost@php.net. If you're able to email credentials to a system that reproduces the issue that'd prob go a long way.

Comment: Wow, thanks @neubert I will contact him.  In the meantime, I have added code that seems to work (in update of my question).  Pretty sure the issue lies in ssh->_get_channel_packet(NET_SSH2_CHANNEL_EXEC, true); returning an extra NULL.  But I will contact him.  Thanks again.